# Windows remembers old DNS suffix

Tags: windows, dhcp

I just changed the DNS domain of my local network from `home.local` to `mydomain.local`, after purchasing `mydomain.com`. I made all the necessary changes in my BIND and DHCP server, and linux clients on the network now have `domain mydomain.local` in their `/etc/resolv.conf` and seem to be working as expected.

However, Windows machines (Win 8.1, not joined to a domain) still seem to hang on to the `home.local` domain in it's DNS Suffix Search List. I have released my lease, removed network profiles, scanned the registry, grep:ed the entire dns/dhcp server for occurences of the old domain, rebooted everything... Still, the windows machines keep searching `home.local`.

Output from `ipconfig /all` on an affected machine:

```
Windows IP Configuration

  Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MY-MACHINE
  Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
  Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
  IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
  WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
  DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home.local

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain.local
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-11-22-33-44-55
  DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
  Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1234:1234:1234:1234%3(Preferred)
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.97(Preferred)
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : den 24 januari 2015 19:42:25
  Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : den 25 januari 2015 19:43:27
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1111:2222:3333:4444%3
                                      192.168.0.1
  DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
  DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 12312312
  DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-11-22-33-44-55-66-77-88-99-AA-BB-CC-DD

  DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
  NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix Search List :
                                      home.local
```

**EDIT**

Note that the connection-specific DNS suffix is correct, but the suffix search list is wrong, both connection specific and general IP configuration.

The WMI queries show the same - the suffix for the connection is correct, but it is not added to the search list, which instead seems to reuse the same suffix as previously. Possibly it remembers this based on the server being the same?

Comment: Which tool used for the _scan the registry_ task? [RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) can find a unicode string located inside a binary value.

Comment: @JosefZ: Just the regular regedit search tool. I'll check out RegScanner.

Comment: @JosefZ: No more matches with RegScanner, unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like *DNS* caching issue. To resolve this, run `cmd` as administrator and perform

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

or even (although the `/allcompartments` switch could seem to be superabundant)

```
ipconfig /allcompartments /flushdns
```

Further hints: `ipconfig /?`

Clearing the *ARP* cache might help as well:

```
arp -d
```

---

**Edit** according to what others advise: Group policy `DNS Suffix Search List` could be found as value `SearchList` in next registry key:

```
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient
```

---

**Edit 2** what output from next CLI commands? Is there listed unwanted DNS suffix?

```
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration get caption, DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration get caption, DNSDomain
```

---

**Edit 3** Check values `NameServer` and `SearchList` in next registry key:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
```

and *under* next registry keys (i.e. in each interface-related subkey):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP6\Parameters\Interfaces
```

To put changes in validity: restart computer.

---

**Edit 4** Check all `NameServerList` value of `REG_MULTI_SZ` type in all keys of next pattern

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters\Interfaces\Tcpip_{interface_CLSID}
```

Next `PowerShell` code should set the DNS suffix search order. [Stolen here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393296(v=vs.85).aspx) as I'm not well-skilled in PS.

```
#First store the suffixes to set in a variable
$suffixes = 'mydomain.local'

#Since this is a static method, get a class object and then call the method. 
$class = [wmiclass]'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration'
$class.SetDNSSuffixSearchOrder($suffixes)
```

As the last resort: disable system restore, restart, check `wmic`  mentioned above...

Comment: I had already tried `/flushdns`, but not with `/allcompartments`. It did not work, unfortunately. The ARP cache didn't help either.

Comment: I don't have the registry key mentioned in the first edit. For the two commands, I do get the unwanted suffix for the first command, but it is correct in the second one.

Comment: `NameServer` and `SearchList` are both empty. `DhcpNameServer` and `DhcpDomain` are both correct, though. None of the interfaces had overrides.

Comment: Re "Edit 4", no luck with the registry there either. For the Powershell part, I probably could do that, but I think that would act as an override, rather than fix the actual problem? Also, it would probably remain even for other networks?

Comment: @carlpett do a search and read [on serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/questions/224160/dns-search-path-on-windows); override to an empty string? I don't know...

Comment: Multiple suffixes like this `$suffixes = 'microsoft.com', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com'`

Answer (score 2):

- Go to your ethernet connection
- Click Properties
- Double click Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4)
- Click Advance
- Click the DNS tab
- Remove home.local

Comment: Thanks, but there is no explicitly set domain there

Answer (score 1):

There may be a GPO being pushed, check Group Policy... Computer Configuration - Policies - Administrative Templates - Network - DNS Client.

There you will find DNS Suffix Search and its settings. If you continue to have trouble, navigate to the following link for [more information.](http://www.ryanjadams.com/2009/10/dns-suffix/)

Comment: Thanks, but the computers are not joined to a domain.

Comment: Please try the following command on the client computer
`ipconfig /registerdns`

Answer (score 1):

Go to

**win+r> ncpa.cpl> go properties which adapter connected> TCP/IPv4>properties> advanced> dns>** below you will see dns suffix tab. 
**remove** dns suffix from tab > **append this dns suffix (in order)**

then > **append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes**

and check > **append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix**

at the end check > **Register this connection's addresses in DNS.**

Comment: Why do you write all in bold?

Comment: Is there any guide about bold?
to make difference between words.

Answer (score 1):

For us, it was that our DHCP server had a scope option that was setting the wrong dns suffix using the "015 DNS Domain Name" option.  Once I corrected that and restarted the affected computer, it picked up the right DNS suffix.